# Is a sum of rational functions with small degree meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

For every $n\in\mathbb N_0$, let $P_n$ be a polynomial of $\mathbb C[z]$ with degree $n^2$. One assumes that for every $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $P_n\mid P_{n+1}$ in $\mathbb C[z]$. Can one assert that the function $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{P_n(z)}$ defines a meromorphic function?

Thanks in advance for any answer

From request: My original problem was this exercise: determine if the function
$$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n^2-1}(z-j)}$$ is a meromorphic function. To have some ideas, I tried to generalize this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to the original problem: Given $R > 0$ choose an index $N$ such that $N^2 -1 > R$. Then
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n^2-1}(z-j)}
= \sum_{n=0}^N \frac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n^2-1}(z-j)}
+  \frac{\sum_{n > N} f_n(z)}{\prod_{j=0}^{N^2-1}(z-j)}
$$
with
$$
 f_n(z) = \frac1{\prod_{j=(N+1)^2-1}^{n^2-1}(z-j)} \, .
$$
is meromorphic in $B_R(0)$ because the series $\sum_{n > N} f_n(z)$ is a uniformly converging series of holomorphic functions in that disk.

This holds for arbitrary $R > 0$, therefore the given series defines a meromorphic function in $\Bbb C$.

The same approach works for $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{P_n(z)}$ with $P_n\mid P_{n+1}$ if the zeros of $P_n$ converge to $\infty$.

It does not work if the zeros of $P_n$  have a finite accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you. It is a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The functions $P_n(z) = z^{n^2}$ have $\deg P_n = n^2$ and $P_n \mid P_{n+1}$, but $\sum P_n(z)^{-1}$ doesn't have a meromorphic continuation across the unit disk by the Fabry gap theorem.

Comment: Thank you. That proves my generalization of the original problem was very dumb.

Comment: It's not dumb at all to try to generalize the problem, but (as suggested below) you have to be careful about the distribution of the zeros of the $P_n$. See the Weierstrass factorization theorem for an example.